# How to include TypeScript files and compile whole file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I have installed the latest version of TypeScript and also the latest version of Web Essentials. I created a new TypeScript project in VS2012.

If have a `utils.ts`:

```
moduls utils
{
    export function getNumber() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

And a `app.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="utils.ts" />

alert(utils.getNumber().toString());
```

The JavaScript files are both compiled seperatly. But to get `app.js` to work properly, the compiled source code of `utils.ts` has obviously to be included.

It does work when I run `tsc app.ts -out app.js` in my console, but I do not want to run it everytime manually.

**Why cannot Web Essentials do the for me?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Web Essentials installed as I love the side by side editing, but I use the TypeScript compiler from within the project file to compile a single output.

The details are here: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Getting-The-Right-Set-Up-For-TypeScript/

But the chunk of code for your project file is:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\$(TypeScriptVersion)\tsc&quot; --out final.js @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

You'll probably find this is mostly already there in your project file and you just need to add the --out flag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did as instructed, but I neither find a `target` tag nor a `BeforeBuild` attribute in the `csproj` file.

Comment: You can add this in if it isn't there - you will also need to check you have `<TypeScriptCompile Include="app.ts" />` in there too. This goes just after the `<Content Include="app.js"><DependentUpon>app.ts</DependentUpon></Content>` section.

Comment: Is there a specific position where I have to include the code? I added it to the root element `<Project>`, but it does not work.

Comment: What is `$(PROGRAMFILES)` and `%(fullpath)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with VS2012 express for Web/TypeScript0.9.0.1 and the above didn't work. In case anyone else has this problem with that setup, I did get a similar workaround going where

1. in Project Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-build event command line I added: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe" --target ES5 $(ProjectDir)app.ts -out $(ProjectDir)Final.js`
2. Modified default.htm to load `Final.js` instead of `app.js`