# TypeScript emit boilerplate code only once

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, typescript

After some more close examination of the code generated from *.ts files I found that if you extend a class, then the boilerplate `__extends` function is copied as many times, as many times you extended anything... Could this be due to me using Web Essentials to compile the TypeScript sources, and thus the `tsc` doesn't know that it needs to write it only once?

Below are my TypeScript-related settings from the project build file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

And I have a bunch of:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)src\Foo.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)src\Bar.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)src\Baz.ts" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

There is a command-line option for tsc, specifically, `--out` for producing a single file rather than a bunch of files, but adding `<Out>` or `<TypeScriptOut>` to the property group didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

It will be generated once for each file. This is because the compiler is run once for each file and does not know that the same function will be defined in another file.

Using the --out flag inserts this function only once at the top of the output file. However there is no option to use this flag in Visual Studio at the moment. You can however Edit your project file manually as Steve has mentioned.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\$(TypeScriptVersion)\tsc&quot; --out final.js @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346708/390330